# Protected Directory existence and creating custom validator in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-validation

I was searching for password strength meter for Yii2. I found [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/) for Yii1. I saw `protected` directory mention there. I'm unable to find this folder. Is it available in Basic Application Template or Advanced Application Template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `protected` directory in Yii2 (neither in basic nor in advanced application template).

Where to place your custom validator - it's up to you.

I'd recommend `components/validators` folder.

Here is [the part](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#creating-validators) of the official guide covering custom validation for Yii2.

Also take a look at [this extension](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-password), maybe it already covers your needs, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: yii2-app-basic/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-gii/components folder is there. In this folder, can i create 'validators' folder ? And, if i declare ' passwordStrength.php' page inside validators folder, will i have to write something new to extend class name in this  passwordStrength.php page. Sorry Mr @Arogachev. I'm new to it. So, asking silly questions. Don't mind.

Comment: It's OK. We all learn. You should not modify any files under `vendor` folder. And Gii is for completely different purposes. Create inside application root folder.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Mr Arogachev.

Comment: As for better understanding, see the official guide link I provided. Yii2 have many things at common with Yii1, but at the same time different in many things.

Answer (score 4):

protected forder is for Yii1

Yii2 Not have this folder

You can use this example code in your model

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['password', 'checkPassword'],

        // other rules
    ];
}

public function checkPassword($attribute, $params)
{
    // no real check at the moment to be sure that the error is triggered
    if(password != OK )
         $this->addError($attribute, 'Your password not valid');
}
```

Comment: you can create your validator in your model

Comment: Thanks Amir. It means a lot.